# Float to Int conversion Swift

Tags: swift, floating-point, int, type-conversion

I want to convert a float value to int.
 For e.g my float value is 40.22 , i need an int value like this 4022.

```
 let price : String  = valueArray.objectAtIndex(5) as! String
 let floatValue : Int = Int(price)! * 100
```

Comment: Has the string (it's not a float) always 2 fractional digits, and if not, what is the expected behavior?

Answer (score 3):

You can try like this:

```
var myInt = Int(40.22*100)
```

or

```
var myInt = Int(price*100)
```

Comment: what if the value is 40.2222?

Answer (score 2):

Here is best solution for it,

```
let price : Float = 40.22

let stringValue : String = "\(price)"

print(stringValue)     //This prints "40.22"

let intString = stringValue.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(".", withString: "")

print(intString)       //This prints "4022"

if let intValue = Int(intString) {
    print(intValue)    //This gives 4022
}
```

Comment: Vote for this solution ;)

Comment: This would convert the different prices `4.02` and `40.20` to the same integer result `402`, and I wonder if that is wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution, and i hope everything goes fine.

```
let price : String  = "40.4534522"
let myStringArr = price.componentsSeparatedByString(".")
let finalString = myStringArr[0] + myStringArr[1]
let requiredInt = Int(finalString)
print(requiredInt!)
```